# OpenCV VideoCapture fails to read frame

Tags: java, opencv

I'm trying to read a frame from an usb camera,
I've compiled the latest OpenCV available on [GitHub](https://github.com/opencv/opencv)

```
Core.VERSION = 4.0.0.dev
```

But when I try to run this code I get:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;

public class OpenCVTest {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mat frame = new Mat();

        VideoCapture videoCapture = new VideoCapture();

        assert videoCapture.open(0);
        assert videoCapture.isOpened();

        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            assert videoCapture.read(frame);
        }
    }
}


[ WARN:0] videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -2147024809
[ WARN:0] videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -2147024809
[ WARN:1] videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147024809
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
    at OpenCVTest.main(OpenCVTest.java:24)
```

I've also tried the [3.4.2-dev branch](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/3.4) but I get the same error, the strange thing is that when i use the prebuild version available [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/tag/3.4.1) my code works flawless, I'm missing something?

Comment: Can you add comment to the post on platform and video libraries in use? There is sometimes the possibility of an issue with camera configuration for the platform.

Comment: I'm using windows 10 creators x64 my webcam is a TeckNet C016 with a resolution of 1280x1024

Comment: May be MSMF can't read from your USB camera. May be the branch was compiled with other video libraries enabled (like ffmpeg). Try checking this.